# Regex: Find lines that do not start with html tag, but end with other tag, and make replace at the beginning

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this lines, I need to make them all paragraph, `<p class="mb-40px"></p>` The first 2 lines, doesn't have html tags, but ending with inappropriate tag. And the third line has also the same inappropriate tag at the end , but had the right tag at the beginning.

```
Vă pare rău pentru ce aţi făcut?”<br />
”Can you love me?”<br />
<p class="mb-40px">Să ne imaginăm nişte răspunsuri ale agresorului.<br />
```

**Must Become:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">Vă pare rău pentru ce aţi făcut?”</p>
<p class="mb-40px">”Can you love me?”</p>
<p class="mb-40px">Să ne imaginăm nişte răspunsuri ale agresorului.</p>
```

My both regex are almost good, but duplicates the first tag in the third line

FIND: `^(.*)(<br />)$`

REPLACE BY: `<p class="mb-40px">\1</p>`

**OR**

FIND: `^(?!<p>)(.+?)(<br />)$`

REPLACE BY: `<p class="mb-40px">\1<\p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:<p class="mb-40px">)?(.+)<br />`
- Replace with: `<p class="mb-40px">$1</p>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                           # begining of line
(?:<p class="mb-40px">)?    # non capture group, optional open p tag
(.+)                        # group 1, 1 or more any character
<br />                      # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]